# How should nail holes be repaired in a gypsum firewall?

Tags: drywall, patching-drywall

I've got a couple nail holes from pictures being hung in the garage that I'd like to patch. The drywall is 5/8" fire-rated. With that in mind, are there any special considerations when patching this wall? Should I be using fire caulk/foam or just use all purpose spackle on it as if it was any other drywall?

Comment: I'm no expert, but it seems to me that spackle or joint compound should be just fine for small nail holes.  After all, they're good enough for drywall joints.  I'm looking forward to an answer from a pro.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just as minor voids left during hanging of the drywall are filled with joint compound, you can do so with nail holes and any other minor penetrations. Many times an installer will miss framing with a screw and pull it out, leaving a similar hole. It's not a concern.